# animar removeAllViews ao recriar view

Tags: android

Eu tenho um scrollview com 6 botões que mudam o fundo de acordo com um numberpicker escolhido anteriormente, Quando eu altero o numero do number picker e ele remove os botões existentes e cria novamente com o fundo correto para aquele numero escolhido, tudo certo até ai, o problema é que quando ele faz essa reconstrução o scrollview pisca, e isso fica bem feio, parece um glitch, teria como animar esta recriação de botões?

Meu metodo:

```
    private void criardias(int diapreparacao) {

    layoutbtns.removeAllViewsInLayout();


    for (int i = 1; i <= 6 ; i++) {
        FancyButton diabtn = new FancyButton(getContext());
        diabtn.setText("Dia " + i);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(135, 135);
        layoutParams.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);
        diabtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        diabtn.setRadius(64);
        diabtn.setTextSize(15);
        diabtn.setRadius(64);
        diabtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selectorbtndia));

        if (i == diapreparacao) {
            diabtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.vermelhoperfil));
            diabtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btndiaatual));
        } else {
            if (i < diapreparacao) {
                diabtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btndiadisponivel));
            } else {
                diabtn.setEnabled(false);
                diabtn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btndiadisabilitado));
            }
        }

        layoutbtns.addView(diabtn);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro da pasta res tem um diretorio com nome "anim", se não tiver você cria essa pasta, e cria um Animation resource file, ou usa algum que tem lá. 
Exemplo de Animation resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="0.8%p"
        android:repeatCount="3"
        android:duration="160"/>
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-0.8%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:repeatCount="3"
        android:duration="160"/>

</set>
```

Agora você pode setar a animação na view ao clickar no botão, ex:

```
TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
Animation animacao = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.SuaAnimacao);
    texto.startAnimation(animacao);
```

Ou então você pode colocar dentro de um delay pra animar antes de mudar os backgrounds, mais ou menos assim:

```
    texto.startAnimation(animacao);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//Executa a função de mudar as coisas
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Aí você chama no início do seu For e já  era papai, tudo bonito